# Strange margin behavior when including jQuery.min.js

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an odd issue with my page layout. The header of my site is bumping down about 50 pixels when I include jQuery.min.js. If I remove jQuery.min.js from the head, then the header displays correctly. How could this be? I don't recall ever changing my CSS.

Any ideas?

**[SITE HERE](http://jonathonmoore.com/sandbox/single.html)**

Comment: it looks like its breaking right after the only script included with https..try including jquery.min as http instead of https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including it using `https` while the site itself is `http`.  Instead you should not include any of the protocol part as it will automatically figure it out.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>‌​
```

Would work fine.

Edit: You are also not closing your `<link>` tags which I think may be the real problem.  You should really run the page through the a http://validator.w3.org/

Edit again: I downloaded the source and opened it in VIM, apparently you have some random invalid characters after that `</script>`.

This is what my text editor is showing:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script><E2><80><8C><E2><80><8B>
```

Delete the line and the one below it and insert them again from some other way.

Comment: Tried this, but there's still an odd margin.

Comment: I think the invalid html is causing the biggest problems right now actually.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: You have some characters that are outside the normal ASCII character set after that script tag.  I would cut and paste the code into notepad then cut and paste it back to remove them.

Comment: That was it. Notepad wasn't able to identify any hidden characters, so I just re-typed the whole script line in again and that fixed it. Thanks for the help! (Note to self...don't always wait until the end to validate). For the sake of knowing, however, any idea how those got there?

Answer (score 2):

Try including your libraries in the `<head>` tag instead of the `<body>`

Comment: They are in the head, aren't they?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing what you're referring to. Sorry!

Comment: It's only in the browser's html but not in the source code (you can see them if you inspect using chrome for example). You jQuery is loading in your body...

Comment: Yeah, I was really confused for a second.